# Windows defender Win32/Persistence.DQ!ml, what is it?

Tags: windows-10, malware-detection, windows-security, windows-defender

I'm trying to figure out what this generic description of malware means, googling it didn't turn up much
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Behavior%3aWin32%2fPersistence.DQ!ml&threatid=2147737492

I'm creating a desktop application/browser plugin. Today when I tried to installing and testing the latest version on windows 10 (earlier versions of the program didn't give cause this problem) windows defender reacted to the executable. It gave me the link above but that just gives some generic user information. It also allowed the program to continue to execute which I thought was odd but maybe more information on what this means might explain why. The program itself is not doing anything shady so I'm sure this is a false positive but I would like to know what Win32/Persistence.DQ!ml means, so I can try to avoid triggering false positives in the future.

Comment: I created a Windows Service and having the same security trigger.